# Declaring properties of variables

Tags: logic

I am doing practice exercises in a book that introduces us to writing math proofs and I notice they all start in a similar way. For example:

$let \ x \ and \ y \in \mathbb{R}. If \ x \ and \ y \geq \ 0, then \ xy \geq0$

starts by saying what the properties of the variables are. Is this just convention or is there anything wrong with saying

$If \ x \ and \ y \geq \ 0, then \ xy \geq0, where \ x \ and \ y \in \mathbb{R}$
?

Comment: There's no difference between "$xy\ge 0$ if $x,y \ge 0$" and "if $x,y\ge 0$ then $xy\ge 0$".  Though I do suspect the human brain (or at least those of us who've grown up in a region where the language is written left-to-right) is better at handling $A\implies B$ statements than $B\impliedby A$ statements.

Comment: Or do you mean that the statement could be written as "If $x,y\ge 0$, then $xy\ge 0$, where $x,y\in \Bbb R$"?  That's also fine.

Comment: Yes, the latter is what I meant. So it is just convention then?

Comment: I've seen it both ways.  There doesn't seem to be any standard convention.

Comment: The former is more readable. The first sentence sets the context or domain of discussion for what is to follow. Always a good idea. It also more closely parallels the formal statement of the theorem: $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:\forall y \in \mathbb{R}: [x\geq 0 \land y\geq 0 \implies x\cdot y\geq 0]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is better to put the first part, that $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, first. Otherwise one doesn't necessarily know what conditions like $xy \geq 0$ even mean. If $x$ and $y$ are sets, for example, this is meaningless. (But as Bye World points out, you can also write "where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$" last.)

That being said, most people would understand the condition "if $x, y \geq 0$" on its own to mean "if $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative real numbers."

Once you've said that you're assuming $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, you can write either:

> "If $x, y \geq 0$, then $xy \geq 0$,"

or

> "We have $xy \geq 0$, if $x,y \geq 0$,"

with no change in meaning. I find the first one a little easier to read.